# determine the expression of an analytic function from given information

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D\rightarrow D$ be analytic and satisfy $f\left(\dfrac {1}{2}\right)=\dfrac {1}{2}$ and $f'(\dfrac {1}{2})=-1$. Find an explicit formula for $f$.$D$ is a unit disc.

My thought:we choose a neighborhood of $\dfrac{1}{2}$ inside the unit disc. From the information we have ,we can express $f$ as $\dfrac{1}{2}+(-1)(x-\dfrac{1}{2})+\ldots$. I don't konw what data we can dig from the given information in order to determine the rest terms of power series.

Comment: What is essential here is that sinse $f : D \rightarrow D$ then we have the implication $|z| < 1 \Rightarrow |f(z)| < 1$. Also note that if an analytic function from the unit disk to the unit disk has two distinct fixed points, then it is constant. Your function already has a fixed point, $\frac{1}{2}$ and thus it can't have another one.

Comment: If it has two fixed points, it's certainly not constant!  I think you mean it's a Möbius transformation.

Comment: see [link](http://mymathforum.com/complex-analysis/11335-analytic-fixed-point.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|\alpha|<1$, define $\varphi_{\alpha}(z)$ by $$\varphi_{\alpha}(z)=\frac{\alpha-z}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}.$$
Then this became an analytic function $\varphi_{\alpha}:D\to D$ which satisfies $\varphi_{\alpha}(0)=\alpha, \varphi_{\alpha}(\alpha)=0$ and $\varphi_{\alpha}\circ\varphi_{\alpha}=id$, i.e. $\varphi_{\alpha}$ is automorphism of $D$ with $\varphi_{\alpha}^{-1}=\varphi_{\alpha}$. Now, define $$g(z):=\varphi_{1/2}(f(\varphi_{1/2}(z)))$$ 
then we can check  $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=-1$ (use chain rule). By Schwarz lemma, we get $g(z)=-z$, i.e. $$f(z)=\frac{5z-4}{4z-5}.$$

Comment: @Dr.MV $\varphi_{\alpha}$ is a good tool to solve problems about analytic function defined on unit disk since it can exchange any points with origin. Also, conditions of this problem reminds me about schwarz lemma.